# Application defined - or object-defines error when adding formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to add a formula within VBA that includes variables, however it keeps throwing the following error:

> Application defined - or object-defines error

This is the code below, **expectedProjectWS** and **budgetLines** are Worksheets. Its basically trying to refer to the **budgetLines** Worksheet.

```
Dim Findo3 As Range

For Each a In refData.Range("G7:G" & LastRow_RefData).Cells

Set Findo3 = budgetLines.Range("B8" & ":" & "B" & lastRow3).Find(a.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    expectedProjectWS.Range("A" & lastAddress).Offset(1, 10).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" _
                    & budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value _
                    & ",BudgetLines!" & budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Address & ":$M$19,12,FALSE)"

Next
```

However, when I debug `budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Address` it returns its value.

Comment: please load the rest of your relevant code, so it will be easier to debug; instead of guessing if `budgetLines` is defined correct as `Worksheet`, if `Findo3` is defined and set correctly as `Range`, etc....

Comment: first, you can simplify your code a little, modify `budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address)` to `Findo3` ; so `budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value` will be `Findo3.Offset(0, -1).Value`. Second, in my test I am getting results and it's working for me, so it's related to how and where you position your data. What value do you get for `lastAddress` ?  What is the Range for `Findo3` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be multi-line, but does not contain line-continuation characters.  Try this:

```
expectedProjectWS.Range("A" & lastAddress).Offset(1, 10).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" _
& budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Value _
& ",BudgetLines!" & budgetLines.Range(Findo3.Address).Offset(0, -1).Address _
& ":$M$19,12,FALSE)"
```

If you still get the same error, ensure that none of your `Range(...).Offset` calls is returning an invalid range.

For example, the following code is attempting to access the Address of an invalid range, and would return the "Application-defined or object-defined error" error, because there is no cell above and to the left of cell "A1": `Range("A1").Offset(-1, -1).Address`

Comment: The first part is not missing, the last edit done to the post, removed the 1 long line, and made it into several lines, without adding this. I'll edit the post once more (to have the code as the PO intended)